# How to fetch stream names from different Project Area in Rational Team Concert using lscm.bat?

Tags: rtc

I am using the following command to get a list of streams.

```
lscm.bat list streams -m 2500 -r https://intranet:9443/ccm1/
```

The problem is that it returns names of streams only from one project area. I am sure that the total number of streams across all project areas is less than 2500, so increasing that number in the hope of getting all stream listed is not the answer.
**How do I make it return streams names from a different project area?** Is there a command line option that I need to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use the --projectarea option and specifying the project area name to list streams from the specified project area.